# SonarQube Jenkins setup in an automated manner?

Tags: python, jenkins, automation, sonarqube, devops

I'm trying to automate the Jenkins setup with SonarQube. What I mean by this is that every time I spin up a Docker container from a Jenkins image, I want to be able to have :

1. SonarQube spun up as well - this part I have taken care of
2. Jenkins integrated with SonarQube already, allowing me to run pipelines directly without needing to set up SonarQube or SonarScanner.

There are things I could do that might work, such as using the Jenkins CLI to configure Sonar (I can't seem to get it to work), or writing code in Python to input or scrape data from the Jenkins/Sonar web UI (This probably is too time-consuming, I'm not sure).

How can I go about doing this?